# If you add a shortcode programmatically, but the code isn't viewed on that request, is it still executed?

Tags: shortcode

Is it expected behavior that the callback of a shortcode is executed even if the result isn't returned, or do shortcodes only execute when they are displayed?

Comment: the shortcode is executed when he is in the content of a post, even if it displays nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortcode callbacks are not executed unless the shortcode is parsed and executed. So if a shortcode has been added, its callback will not run unless the shortcode has been used somewhere on the page, or executed manually in a function or template that has been used, and it will only be run at the moment that the shortcode is parsed.

So the act of registering a shortcode with `add_sortcode()` alone will not execute the callback function.